# Rust, my module introduction suddenly encountered a problem

Tags: rust

This is a problem that has never occurred before, and it suddenly appeared after I added the Excel function

```rust
use crate::common::offic::excel; // <<--
use clap::Parser;
use jni::objects::*;
use jni::JNIEnv;
use std::path::Path;  
use HspiceCompiler::hspice::spice; // <<-- 

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about)]
pub struct Args {
    #[clap(help = "Hspice file name")]
    pub file_name: String,
    #[clap(short, long)]
    pub output_path: String,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    let spice_file = Path::new(&args.file_name);

    let output_path = Path::new(&args.output_path);

    loading(args);

    spice_file.try_exists().expect("Can't access hspice file");
    let mut reader = spice::Reader::new();
    let data_iter = reader.read(spice_file);
    reader.analysis_iter(data_iter);

    excel::write_to_excel(data_iter, output_path);
}
fn loading(args: Args) {
...
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `common` in the crate root
 --> src/bin/run.rs:1:12
  |
1 | use crate::common::offic::excel;
  |            ^^^^^^ could not find `common` in the crate root
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `HspiceCompiler`
 --> src/bin/run.rs:5:5
  |
5 | use HspiceCompiler::common::offic::excel;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `HspiceCompiler`
```

my github -> run.rs : https://github.com/llllishuo/menghan_Hspice_Compiler/blob/main/src/bin/run.rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crate` refers to the root module of the [crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/appendix/glossary.html#crate), which in this case is *src/bin/run.rs*. If you want to refer to the library crate in the same [package](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/appendix/glossary.html#package), you need to refer to it by the name of the package.

```rust
use HspiceCompiler::common::offic::excel;
```

However, your package doesn't currently have a rust library, since your Cargo.toml only includes a [dynamic system library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html):

```ini
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

If you want to use the library also as a rust library, you should also include `lib`.

```ini
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
```

This will also fix your second error.